# csv file not found Juypterlab python3

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-lab

**Goal:** import a csv file with pandas

**Code used:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data/master_data_complete.csv')
```

I have done the following:

- uploaded the csv file to the folder 'data'
- checked to make sure the original file is in fact saved as a csv
- tried creating a new folder called 'mydata' and uploading the csv there (same result with this new filepath)
- quit and reloaded jupyterlab
- right click the file I wish to import and 'copy file path', so I'm sure the file path is accurate

**Outcome:**

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'data/master_data_complete.csv' does not exist: b'data/master_data_complete.csv'

Comment: use full path..

Comment: use `pwd` or `os.getcwd()` to show the current dir.

Comment: @johnny That is where I am having trouble. I am using jupyterlab in my browser. I uploaded the csv file to the 'data' folder. As far as I can tell, 'data' is the directory I should start with in the file path name. Is there a folder before 'data' that I am missing?

Comment: @Ferris Thanks, that worked. I am still figuring out how jupyter works. The correct filepath after I ran os.getcwd() was '/home/jovyan/demo/data/master_data_complete.csv'. What's the short answer for 'What is /jovyan/?

Comment: Use ```!ls``` or ```!cd```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is maybe and i repeat maybe in the path,
you are usin and absolute path

```
'data/master_data_complete.csv'
```

you can try with a relative path

```
'./data/master_data_complete.csv'
```

but only if the notebook and the data folder are in the same folder

```
-parent
   -notebook
   -data
      -master_data_complete.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.getcwd()
```

I found the working directory and added the file name onto the end of it. I was able to import it.

> '/home/jovyan/data/demo'